# Japanese prostitution in 1940s

Tags: japan, 1930s, 1940s

I've been looking around on the web for information about prostitutes in japan in the 1940s. I am unable to find anything helpful, as all that is mentioned are "Comfort Women". I need information about Japanese prostitutes.

Here is my question.

Were young girls sometimes sold into prostitution to pay off family debt? And if so, what were they called?

Comment: Note that The 1940's is during and after the war with the US. Two very different times. Possibly also quite different from before the war with the US.

Comment: Did you ask this question only last week?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel No, he posted a question that was in fact a whole set of different questions, it was closed, and he was asked to ask the questions separately.

Comment: Some comfort women were Japanese , FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

[Sayo Masuda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobiography_of_a_Geisha) was sold to a geisha house to be an [onsen geisha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsen_geisha) to pay for her father's medical treatment.

Geishas are not the same as prostitutes, but her job was a sexualized one. I haven't read her book, but the Wikipedia summary mentions that her virginity was sold off five times while she was an onsen geisha.